# jQuery Mobile changePage with pop transition?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use changePage function in jQuery Mobile, but I want the page to open as a popup dialog.

I tried this:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#confirmbox', 'pop');
```

That's supposed to work according to the docs here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/api/methods.html

But it doesn't. I still get a slide transition... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close. This is how you perform a changePage with a transition.

```
$.mobile.changePage('#confirmbox',{transition: 'pop'});
```

Edit: I have no idea why the way the documentation does it doesn't work. It should.

Comment: Wow, I knew that was an alternative way of doing it, but since they should be equal according to the docs I never even tried it... But it worked like a charm all of a sudden! Thanks!